# Angular 6 Dynamic Complex Model-Driven Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm trying to create a form which is built dynamically according to a certain model using Angular's reactive forms. The model is a complex object **which can change**, and contains nested objects and values, for example (in TypeScript notation):

#### model.d.ts

```ts
interface Model {
    // ... other stuff
    config: { // complex object which can change, here's an example for some structure
        database: {
            uri: string;
            name: string;
        };
        server: {
            endpoint: {
                host: string;
                port: number;
            };
            requestTimeoutMs: number;
        };
    };
}
```

Using this object, I built a `FormGroup` like so:

#### form.component.ts

```ts
@Component({
    // ...
    templateUrl: './form.component.html'
})
export class FormComponent {
    @Input() model: Model;
    public form: FormGroup;

    // instantiating the whole form
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = new FormGroup({
            // ... instantiating other controls using the model,
            config: new FormGroup({}),
        });
        // building the config form using model.config which is dynamic
        this.buildForm(this.form.get('config') as FormGroup, this.model.config);
    }

    // helper functions used in the template
    public isGroup(control: AbstractControl): control is FormGroup {
        return control instanceof FormGroup;
    }
    public typeOf(value: any): string {
        return typeof value;
    }

    // building the config form
    private buildForm(group: FormGroup, model: object): void {
        for (const key in obj) {
            const prop = obj[key];
            let control: AbstractControl;
            if (prop instanceof Object) { // nested group
                control = new FormGroup({});
                this.buildForm(control as FormGroup, prop);
            } else { // value
                control = new FormControl(prop);
            }
            group.addControl(control);
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected and creates the form according to the object. I know this doesn't check for arrays and `FormArray`s, because I don't use them currently.

After building the form, I'm trying to display the whole form in my template, which is where I've got a problem. This is my template:

#### form.component.html

```html
<form [ngForm]="form" (ngSubmit)="...">
    <!-- ... other parts of the form -->
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="formItemTemplate"
                  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{parent: form, name: 'config': model: model; level: 0}">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #formItemTemplate let-parent="parent" let-name="name" let-model="model" let-level="level">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="isGroup(parent.get(name)) ? groupTemplate : controlTemplate"
                      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{parent: parent, name: name, model: model, level: level}">
        </ng-container>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #groupTemplate let-parent="parent" let-name="name" let-model="model" let-level="level">
        <ul [formGroup]="parent.get(name)">
            <li>{{name | configName}}</li>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let controlName of parent.get(name) | keys">
                <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="formItemTemplate"
                              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{name: controlName, model: model[name], level: level + 1}">
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </ul>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template #controlTemplate let-name="name" let-model="model" let-level="level">
        <li class="row">
            <div class="strong">{{name | configName}}</div>
            <ng-container [ngSwitch]="typeOf(obj[name])">
                <input type="text" *ngSwitchCase="'string'" [formControlName]="name">
                <input type="number" *ngSwitchCase="'number'" [formControlName]="name">
                <input type="checkbox" *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'" [formControlName]="name">
            </ng-container>
        </li>
    </ng-template>
</form>
```

Let me break it down for you, in case the component's template isn't understood:

I have `formItemTemplate` whose job is to distinguish if `parent.get(name)` (the child control) is a `FormGroup` or a `FormControl`. If the child control is a `FormGroup`, a child template of `groupTemplate` is created, otherwise `controlTemplate`.

In `groupTemplate` I created a `ul` node which binds `[formGroup]` to `parent.get(name)` (the child group) and **in it** (hierarchically) then proceed to create a `formItemTemplate` template *for each control* of that child group, whose control names I got using a `keys` pipe which I've created, which just returns `Object.keys()` for the given value. Bascially - recursion.

In `controlTemplate` I just create a new `li` and in it I create an input which binds `[formControlName]` to the `name` given in `[ngTemplateOutletContext]`.

The problem is that I get the following error:

> Cannot find control with the name: '...'

I know it happens if you bound `[formControlName]` on a control with a name that isn't found in the scope of the `[formGroup]` bound to your FormGroup. That is weird, because I even checked in DevTools and can see that `ng-reflect-form="[object Object]"` attribute is applied to the `ul` of the group, which means it indeed is bound and most probably to the correct `FormGroup`.

When debugging `isGroup()` with additional arguments passed from the template's context (such as `model` and `name`) I've noticed that `isGroup()` is called many times for each object, sequentially, and not once for each object, like so:

1. config
2. database
3. uri
4. config - again? why? why wasn't it called for `name`?
5. database
6. uri
7. name
8. config - 3rd time???
9. database
10. uri
11. name
12. server - should've been called in the 5th iteration

And then it crashes without completing the iteration over the whole model, unless I click on some input in my component, which is *so weird*.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658033/angular-4-dynamic-form-with-nested-groups) which is similar to mine but it wasn't helpful for problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own question by adding `[formGroup]="parent"` to the `li` element in `controlTemplate`. Whoops!